# How to find optimal items to match as many sets as possible

Tags: algorithm, subset, combinatorics

I want to know which items, with a certain limit, that results in as many fully matched sets as possible.

Sets can contain between 1 to 20 items.

```
set1 { 1, 3, 5}
set2 { 2, 3, 8, 10}
set3 { 1, 5, 8, 10}
set4 { 1, 3, 5, 9 }
......

Input 4 returns set 1,4 with chosen items { 1,3,5,9 }
Input 6 returns set 1,2,3 with chosen { 1,2,3,5,8,10 }

Input can be any value from 1 to n
```

Is there any known algoritm that solves this problem?

Comment: Do you want the intersection of sets, with length = input as output?

Comment: @notnotparas Sorry, I don't understand the question. Can you please clarify? Thanks. :)

Comment: I mean to say, that given the input "4" or "9",is it the length of output set? Does the task requires you to output the intersection of given sets with this length?

Comment: Sets that contains more items than input could not be selected but as long as they have all items matched means it's fulfilled. Input 6 = sets with less lenght ^^^

Comment: This seems very much related to the [Set cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem) which is known to be NP-complete